# How to add content after or before block using XML in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks, adminhtml

I what to append content in block using XML file. Please check below image

[image]

I have added below code but it is overtiring content. (I want to appending).

```
<reference name="order_items">
      <action method="addColumnRender">
         <column>name</column>
         <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
         <template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
      </action> 
</reference>
```

I have checked core file there are creating block programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the block names/aliases of both blocks you can move the block that is appearing first to display AFTER the block you want to appear first.

In this example I will call the block you want to appear first `first.block`, and the block you want to appear second `second.block` which has an alias of `secondBlockAlias`.

```
<reference name="order_items">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>secondBlockAlias</alias>
    </action>

    <action method="insert">
        <block>second.block</block>
        <siblingName>first.block</siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Block is creating using this  code ` $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_columnRenders[$column]['block'])->setTemplate($this->_columnRenders[$column]['template'])->setRenderedBlock($this);` How can I know block name?

Comment: I have added this code in config.xml file `<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
  <reference name="order_items"><block type="adminhtml/sales_items_column_name" name="sales.order.product.customizer.info"  as="salesOrderCustomizerInfo" template="productcustomizer/sales/order/view/additional-1.phtml"/><action method="unsetChild"><alias>salesOrderCustomizerInfo</alias></action><action method="insert"><block>sales.order.product.customizer.info</block><siblingName>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</siblingName><after>1</after></action></reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>` but it is not working